# Part III of the Mathematical Tripos at Cambridge (Pure Maths) with scholarship, and US PhD applications

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters

In [some](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40352/how-much-weight-does-the-tripos-iii-carry-for-further-phd-admissions/40356#40356) other [questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17922/benefits-of-doing-part-iii-at-cambridge-pure-math-for-us-phd-applications), it has been noted that for certain programs at Cambridge, such as Part III of the Mathematical Tripos, one will not have had sufficient faculty contact to obtain strong recommendation letters. Additionally, no courses will show up on your transcripts until the end-of-year examinations (is what I have gathered from the answers to the above questions).

Thus, I imagine attending Part III may not significantly strengthen an application. Does attending Part III, such as on a Churchill Scholarship, carry significantly more weight to a graduate admissions committee?

Comment: I suspect that it is more about what you do in a program than what scholarships you got before it began. No direct experience, though.

Comment: See the following for how US doctoral applications work. Other answers for other places are there also. Note that a masters isn't needed for applicants.  https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/176909/75368